# Verify remote file exists with SplFileInfo

Tags: php, spl

I'm trying to copy a remote file to my server.  Before doing this, I want to test of the file exists.  The following code does not work, even though I have manually verified that the file exists on the remote server.  I have PHP's allow_url_fopen set to On.  Is there something I am missing?  The old procedural method file_exists() is what I'm looking to replicate.

```
   //...
   $fileInfo = new \SplFileInfo($imageLocation);
   if($fileInfo->isFile()) {
      echo "doesn't exist";
   } else {
      echo "exists, so copy file here";
   }
```

Comment: Instead of using SplFileInfo, why don't you use the mechanisms of the protocol used for file copying? If it's FTP it's easy to check if file is there, if it's HTTP it's easy to check if file's there..

Comment: At this point in the code, I will not be sure if it is a local file or a remote file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no equivalent of [`file_exists()`](http://php.net/file_exists) for the `SplFileInfo` class.

`SplFileInfo::isFile()` is a different check, which correlates with the `is_file()` function (they share underlying code).

You could call the `file_exists()` function on `$imageLocation`, provided it references a stream wrapper that supports `stat()` functionality. Wrappers such as `file://`, `phar://` and `ftp://` (the latter only partially) support this.

Unfortunately the `http://` (and `https://`) wrapper *does not support `stat()` calls*. This means `file_exists()`, and other functions that call `stat()`, will return `false`.

Answer (score 2):

```
$fileInfo->getRealPath();
```

return false if don't exist